# QuickSort not fully working

Tags: java, quicksort

A quicksort algorithm that I've adapted from multiple sources isn't working fully and I can't figure out what's wrong with it. I think there is a off-by-one error somewhere but I've been trying this for an hour now with no different outcome.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void serialSort(List<T> list){
    if (list == null || list.size() <= 1) {
        return;
    }
    T pivot = list.get(list.size() / 2 - 1);
    int i = 0;
    int j = list.size() - 1;
    while (i <= j){
        while (list.get(i).compareTo(pivot) == -1){
            i++;
        }
        while (list.get(j).compareTo(pivot) == 1){
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
            Collections.swap(list, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (0 < j)
        serialSort(list.subList(0, j));
    if (i < list.size())
        serialSort(list.subList(i, list.size()));
}
```

I'm supposed to adapt this to a multi-threaded version but I'd like to fix the error first.

Example input:

```
[2, 9, 4, 1, 7, 2, 1, 1, 6, 6, 3, 8, 4, 7, 6, 7, 8, 6, 3, 3, 3, 1, 4, 1, 1, 2, 9, 7, 7, 2]
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9]
```

Comment: Is this an assignment or for production?  If the first, go through it by hand with larger and larger unsorted lists until you understand the problem (this is a great opportunity to learn unit testing).  If the latter, forget this and use one of the implementations already present in the Java runtime.

Comment: Did you override your compareTo methode? Normaly compareTo shold return 0, less than 0 or more than 0. Per default it isn't specified that it returns exactly 1 or -1.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=quick+sort+java&oq=quick+sort+java&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2351j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=quicksort+java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As mentioned by @FFritz, use `< 0` and `> 0` for your `compareTo` comparisons (this is just good practice in general).
2. Use `j + 1` when building the first `subList` for the recursion.

This code works:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void serialSort(List<T> list){
    if (list == null || list.size() <= 1) {
        return;
    }
    T pivot = list.get(list.size() / 2 - 1);
    int i = 0;
    int j = list.size() - 1;
    while (i < j){
        while (list.get(i).compareTo(pivot) < 0){
            i++;
        }
        while (list.get(j).compareTo(pivot) > 0 && j > i){
            j--;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
            Collections.swap(list, i, j);
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    }
    if (0 < j)
        serialSort(list.subList(0, j + 1));
    if (i < list.size())
        serialSort(list.subList(i, list.size()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that List.subList(int, int) is this from the java documentation:

```
Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, 
inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive.
```

As I suspected it was a off by one error. I wasn't including the last element of the "left" sublist in every recursive call. Doing this fixed it:

```
if (0 < j)
        serialSort(list.subList(0, j + 1));
```